# Sinalizar respostas de quem fez a pergunta?

Tags: debate

Tenho percebido casos assim:

- O usuário faz a pergunta sobre algum problema específico
- A pergunta permanece algum tempo sem respostas ou sem respostas corretas
- Depois de tempo quem fez a pergunta consegue resolver e posta a solução como resposta
- Alguém vai lá e ***sinaliza*** a resposta por ser muito curta ou conter apenas código

Acontece que nesses casos não faz sentido sinalizar, pois a resposta ***é*** a correta. Talvez o pessoal apenas não presta atenção e não percebe que quem respondeu é a mesma pessoa que fez a pergunta.

Pra citar um caso: [Exibindo registros em tabela criada dinamicamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22902/exibindo-registros-em-tabela-criada-dinamicamente/23102#23102)

É importante dizer: Se você não sabe se uma pergunta/resposta deve ser fechada, ***pule*** e deixe os outros decidirem. É muito melhor do que tomar uma decisão incorreta.

Comment: "Se você não sabe se uma pergunta/resposta deve ser fechada, pule e deixe os outros decidirem. É muito melhor do que tomar uma decisão incorreta." Isso poderia estar em negrito, de vermelho e piscando na fila de análises.

Comment: Não esquecendo que pode ser a resposta correta mas descontextualizada por falta de explicação, isso também pode ser sinalizado.

Comment: @JorgeB. foram essas as palavras que eu tentei colocar na minha resposta mas não me vieram à cabeça no momento em que escrevia :p

Comment: Me desculpe, mas no caso da resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22902/exibindo-registros-em-tabela-criada-dinamicamente/23102#23102 , para mim não explica o problema da falha (que está claro sendo um problema no reuso do `mysql_query` em `$row_rsRegistro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRegistro);` e após `while($r = mysql_fetch_array($rsRegistro)){`), em outras palavras, a resposta especifica está "errada". Ele não teve paciência de esperar uma resposta, talvez se tivesse editado a pergunta (o titulo não descreve o problema).

Answer (score 11):

Você deve analisar considerando que são pessoas completamente diferentes, uma perguntando e outra respondendo.

Imagine uma hipotética resposta "correta":

**Resposta**

> Consertado, tinha faltado um ponto e vírgula.

Onde faltou o maldito ponto e vírgula??? Por mais que a resposta seja "correta" ela não será de proveito para absolutamente mais ninguém além do próprio autor da pergunta, que sabia exatamente onde faltava o ponto e vírgula. Ou seja, se ele guardar informações essenciais para ele e não explicar detalhadamente como consertar um determinado erro, pode ser que a resposta não seja tão correta como se imagina.

A regra é a mesma para todo e qualquer tipo de publicação, seja para votar positivamente, negativamente, fechar, etc.. Você deve sempre considerar o **conteúdo das publicações** e jamais quem foi o publicador.

PS: eu não li o link que você passou, estou respondendo de uma maneira geral.

Comment: O problema é que em casos muito específicos, como o do ponto e vírgula faltando: ***(1)*** Se o problema é esse, não vai existir resposta melhor do que "faltou o ponto e vírgula" e ***(2)*** em determinados casos é praticamente impossível alguém descobrir o que há de errado. Neste caso é melhor ele dar esta resposta para ajudar quem eventualmente pesquisar no Google pelo mesmo problema, do contrário a pergunta ficará para sempre sem resposta.

Comment: Talvez meu exemplo não tenha sido muito bom, mas o que eu quis dizer tá explicado logo em seguida na mesma frase. Se eu pensar em um exemplo melhor que o `;` eu atualizo.

Comment: @Andrey mas a resposta **deveria ser** "Falta um ponto e virgula na linha 10" e **não** "faltava um ponto e virgula" mais o código fica um terror para quem vai ler.

Comment: @Jorge Correto. O que eu quis dizer é que certas perguntas é impossível de se descobrir o erro (por falta de informação, etc.). Então nesse caso é melhor ter uma resposta ruim do que nenhuma resposta. Lembre-se que há muitos que abandonam perguntas e nunca mais se dão o trabalho de publicar a solução. Quem se dá o trabalho de publicar a solução, nós ainda vamos deletar a resposta?

Comment: As vezes prefiro que não tenha resposta nenhuma do que andar a perder tempo numa resposta sem valor @Andrey. Depende muito. Eu naquele caso avisava o AP e depois se ele nada disser se a resposta for de baixa qualidade, é apagar mesmo.

Comment: @Jorge Eu penso nas pessoas que enfrentam problemas parecidos e procuram solução no Google, por elas eu manteria a resposta.

Comment: @Andrey mas ter uma resposta que não ajuda só vai confundir quem procura a solução.

Answer (score 6):

Cada caso é um caso, se for realmente uma resposta que sirva para a pergunta, **não importa o tamanho**, esta deverá ser aceita como tal.

Por outro lado alguns usuários postam como resposta uma *"atualização"* de sua pergunta o que deveria ser feito por meio de edição e isto deve sim ser sinalizado.

E concordo com o que disse, **se não souber distinguir** se a resposta é válida ou não, **o ideal é pular.**