# Autor responde a pergunta, mas com péssima qualidade

Tags: debate, fechamento, sinalização, qualidade, responder-a-si-mesmo

Sei que existe uma pergunta antiga (de 2015) que aborda basicamente o mesmo ponto, porém não foi respondida definitivamente. [Pergunta de baixa qualidade, porém, aceitável e respondida pelo próprio autor](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2657/pergunta-de-baixa-qualidade-por%C3%A9m-aceit%C3%A1vel-e-respondida-pelo-pr%C3%B3prio-autor)

Tenho visto uma situação onde o próprio Autor da Pergunta posta a Resposta, porém com péssima qualidade, muitas vezes com uma única frase tipo:

- Solucionado estava faltando um JAR...
- Achei o erro era conflito de classes no CSS...
- Faltava uma dependência...

Esse tipo de resposta as vezes é marcado como "Baixa Qualidade", no entanto é o que resolveu o problema, e remove-la poderia fazer outros usuários perder o tempo com algo que já foi resolvido.

O que fazer então? **Votar para Fechar** ou **Recomendar exclusão** ou deixa como **"Parece ok"** na fila de Analises?

**Ex:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Use o "Recomendar exclusão", o autor claramente pensa que isto é um fórum de suporte técnico e não um site de conteúdo comunitário.

Comment: Pois é percebo a mesma coisa, porém pode vir outro usuário bem intencionado e fica quebrando a cabeça com algo já resolvido. Nesse caso a Pergunta também deve ser marcada para Fechar? Eu não sei o que é pior nesse caso, deixar a Resposta tosca e evitar que alguém perca o tempo, ou Remover a Resposta e correr o risco de alguém perder o tempo tentado ajudar.

Comment: Mas se você leu a resposta e notou pela resposta que o erro foi por parte do autor então tem que votar como fora do escopo > Erro de digitação, claro você não é obrigado a nada, mas se você se preocupa com isto de uma pessoa ter que se esforçar com isto então seu voto de fechamento é fundamental... Ao votar para fechar a pergunta vai pra fila de analise e assim mais 4 pessoas irão analisar a pergunta e votar, pronto :)

Comment: Eu adotaria o mesmo critério do Renan na resposta abaixo, mas não votaria negativo nem na pergunta* e nem na resposta. `(*)Exceto se a pergunta merecer o voto.`... como a resposta é esdrúxula mesmo, não vou perder reputação votando negativo em algo cuja expectativa é ser removido.

Comment: Relacionado: [Sinalizar respostas de quem fez a pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1778/3117)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> - Solucionado estava faltando um JAR...
> - Achei o erro era conflito de classes no CSS...
> - Faltava uma dependência...

Todos esses casos podem ser resumidos em um só. Para a pergunta:

[image: E tchau e benção.]

E para a resposta:

[image: Isso não ajuda a resolver o problema]

Afinal, "já achei, era só um erro meu" não seria aceito mesmo que a pergunta ainda fosse boa.

Nesses casos eu ainda aproveito para dar voto negativo na pergunta e na resposta, já que ambas não possuem nenhuma utilidade prática.

Comment: Renan então o procedimento seria "Recomendar exclusão" e depois ir lá e votar para "Fechar" a pergunta? Essa dúvida é quando o próprio autor responde falando que resolveu e não explica... Atualizei a resposta com uma imagem

Comment: @hugocsl entendi, vou editar minha resposta também.

Comment: Esse "não é uma resposta" nunca teve efeito, ao menos não no que se trata de pessima qualidade, o efeito foi tão negativo que até tomei puxão de orelha de 2 moderadores, mesmo a resposta estando absurdamente errada.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu acho que uma resposta errada é diferente de uma não-resposta.

Comment: @Renan sim, concordo, mas existe o 'baixa qualidade' e o 'não é uma resposta', quero comentar que no sentido de qualidade, que parece que era a intenção do autor o sinalizar foi um caminho das pedras e até a fila de analise pareceu ter um efeito melhor sobre isto (mesmo eu sendo tão cético sobre a fila de analises), mas tudo bem não vou mudar de assunto aqui.